# How to define scala type for no argument function?

Tags: scala, syntax-error, scala-2.8

This works

```
def func(f: => Int) = f
```

This dosn't (inside class for example)

```
type EmptyFunct = => Int
```

or

```
 type EmptyFunct = (=> Int)
```

Scala version 2.9
Two questions:

1. Why dosn't syntax sugar work in second case?
2. How to define this function without syntax sugar?

Comment: Can you give an example of the usage of `EmptyFunct` that shows why `() => Unit` doesn't fit your need?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

=> Int is not exactly a function without parameter, it is an Int argument with call by name passing convention. (Of course, that is rather fine a point, as it is implemented by passing a function without parameter ).

The function without argument is written `() => Int`. You can do `type EmptyFunct = () => Int`.

It is not a type. Inside func, f will be typed as an Int. An argument of type () => Int will not.

```
def func(f: => Int) = f *2
```

> func (: => Int) Int

But

```
def func(f: () => Int) : Int = f*2
```

> error: value * is not a member of () => Int

Comment: So there are no way to create collection of no arg (: =>Unit) functions?

Comment: See my response: `Collection[Function0[Unit]]`

Comment: If you were looking for (: => Unit *) repeated arguments, it is not allowed. Indeed, that could only be Seq[Unit] (Seq contains values, not arguments calling conventions). And be quite useless. What you want is Seq[Function0[Unit]] (or Seq[() => Unit], it means the same thing). Notation will be less convenient : () => x += 1 instead of x+= 1.

Comment: To define a collection: `val c: List[()=>Unit] = List( () => println("hello"), () => println("world") )`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Function0`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function0)

In the first case it does not work because you declare a non argument Function but because you indicates that the parameter is called by name.

Comment: This is not solution to my problem. Because Function0 is actually has type () => T not (=> T) which as I undertand not function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much sense in a method, returning an int, invoked with no parameter. Either it returns a constant, so you could use the constant, or it would use a var?

So let's go with a var:

```
var k = 10 
val fi = List (() => k * 2, () => k - 2)
val n = fi(0)
n.apply 
k = 11
n.apply
```

result is 20, then 22.

Comment: "I don't see much sense in a method, returning an int, invoked with no parameter." A counter ?

Comment: Or any callback function which has all its context in creation phase